# Detect start of a new band

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

Using iReport, how do you set a variable (could be a parameter, or a value in the `REPORT_PARAMETERS_MAP`) to `Boolean.TRUE` at the start of a new band?

There are some fields in the header that should only be displayed after a specific band has started being filled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, it does not wirk that way. It goes straight from the header, passing thru each band header down to the detail band and back to the footer. That's the way one can set sums in the footer of a band, being calculated from the data available at that segregation level. But the filling process for a jasperreports document is pretty straightforward.

Comment: I can create a variable that is set to `TRUE` at the end of a band (using subreport return values, as both Detail bands only contain subreports), but I could not find a way to detect the start of the band. The variable values goes: FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE FALSE. The "TRUE" indicates the end of the `Detail 1` band. I cannot figure out how to leverage that.

Answer (score 0):

In the properties of each text field you have two options available for this issue: "Evaluation Time" and "Evaluation Group". These options can be used to control the filling time of the field.

Comment: When I was tackling the problem, I tried all sorts of variations on Report, Page, Band, etc. for the timing and grouping. Nothing worked.